# How do you say "your heart skips a beat" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, idiom, phrase-request

Ben walked into the room and her heart skipped a beat.

> Ben betrat das Schlafzimmer und sie wurde überrascht.

How do you say "your heart skips a beat" in German? Can I use "überraschen" in this context?

Answer (score 10):

In the context of fright or fear common German idiomatic expressions are:

> Ihr **[stockte](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Herz)** vor Schreck das Herz.
>   Ihr blieb vor Schreck (fast) das Herz **[stehen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/stehen_bleiben)**.

Comment: But be aware of the difference: "skipping a beat" is a short heartbeat-anomaly, "Ihr blieb fast das Herz stehen" equals a near-death experience.

Comment: @Twinkles: people still say that... they also say *"ich bin vor Angst (fast) gestorben"* or *"Ich habe mich zu Tode erschrocken"* which obviously was not true. ;)

Comment: Stockte das Herz? Das ist wohl eher die wörtliche Übersetzung die zumindestens sehr ungebräuchlich ist.

Comment: Vielleicht wird es weniger gehört, weil es zum gehobenen Wortschatz gehört oder weil die Verwendung weniger wird. Ungebräuchlich ist es aber definitiv noch nicht.

Comment: Vielleicht mit _stockte der Atem_ verwechselt?

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu: nein, keine Verwechslung. Es ist eine (gehobene) Wendung, die genau so im verlinkten Duden-Eintrag aufgelistet ist.

Answer (score 8):

Since the literal translation is not common in German you should search for other idioms that would fit better depending on context, like one of these:

> "Ihr stockte der Atem" (surprised/shocked)
>
> "Ihr blieb der Atem weg" (surprised/awed)
>
> "Ihr schlug das Herz bis zum Hals" (nervous/scared)
>
> "Ihr fiel das Herz in die Hose" (surprised/terrified)
>
> "Ihr Herz schlug höher" (excited/adrenaline-rushed)

Answer (score 5):

I'd favor

> Ben trat ins Zimmer und ihr Herzschlag setzte für einen Moment aus.

`Für einen Moment` would emphasize the temporary nature of her surprise – in fact she might have been shocked that much that her heart would not start to beat again.

However, the difference to [Michael's answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/11581/1224) is very subtle and most readers / listeners would understand it in the same way.

I would not use *überraschen* in this context; I think it is not strong enough. You might opt for other idiomatic expressions:

- Sie erstarrte vor Schreck. (*She froze for fright*)
- Sie war zu Donner gerührt. (*She was thunderstruck*)

which aren't as close to the original, though.

Answer (score 2):

The closest idiom would be:

> Ben betrat das Schlafzimmer und ihr Herz setzte aus.

"sie wurde überrascht" is of course the implied cause.

Answer (score 2):

I would say:

> Mein Herz machte einen Sprung

or

> Mein Herz machte einen Satz

translated to: My Heart made a jump/step.

But both is more used in situation where you are more happy then shocked like the other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In your given example "überraschen" is less emotional than "her heart skipped a beat". The closest translations would be

> [...] und ihr stockte vor Schreck der Atem.

or

> [...] und ihr rutschte[/fiel] vor Schreck das Herz in die Hose.